# How to reduce .so file compile by go build plugin

Tags: go

soMain.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    )

func ContextTest(ctx context.Context){
    msg := ctx.Value("myStruct")
    fmt.Println("request:",msg)
}
```

compile order

```
go build -a -buildmode=plugin -ldflags="-w -s" soMain.go
```

file size

```
[root@dwrj60136 about_so]# ls -ls
   4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     160 March  29 10:48 soMain.go
2464 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2520168 March  30 15:16 soMain.so
```

How can i reduce this .so file size, And guarantees the usability of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i reduce this .so file size [?]

You cannot.

Your question looks like a XY problem because it doesn't matter how large the generated plugin .so files are in any normal use case for plugins.